# How to count a group by function?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

I'm trying to count all columns in a table using the group function.
What I tried is:

```
SELECT count(*) from persdat group by zulage > 0;
```

Which printed:

```
   count
  -------
    3
    5
```

This is the table itself:

```
 pname      Zulage
--------------------
 Eifer      1200.00
 Meyer      0.00
 Strom      90.00
 Luft       250.00
 Meieris    NULL
 Volt       1500.00
 Bind       900.00
 Meier      NULL
```

Meaning it counted everything that was 0 and also everything that was above 0. I want it to only show me whats above 0.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (Formatted text please, not images.)

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
SELECT count(*) from persdat WHERE zulage > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select count(*)
from persdat
where zulage > 0;
```

In MySQL, the expression `zulage > 0` is a boolean that is evaluated as a number.  If you run:

```
select (zulage > 0), count(*)
from persdat
group (zulage > 0);
```

Then you will see what is happening with your query.